# Relation between coefficients of characteristic polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

I have read that for a characteristic polynomial of a matrix $M$, say
$$\sum_i \alpha_i T^{n-i},$$

where $\alpha_i=1$, satisfies
$$\max_{i} |\alpha_i|^{1/i} \leq C |\det M|^{1/n} $$

for a certain constant $C$. Why is that true? Even for $n=2$ I am not at ease, it would be a bound of $a+b$ (the eigenvalues) by $\sqrt{ab}$?

Comment: What does the constant $C$ depend on?

Comment: At first this seemed impossible; it would give a bound on the coefficients of any polynomial in terms of one coefficient.. I was missing the condition "where $\alpha_i=1$". _Given_ that $\alpha_i=1$, writing the conclusion the way you did seems very curious, because then $|\alpha_i|^{1/i}$ is just $1$. SO: are you certain you've stated this correctly?